# How to build tensorflow object detection model for custom classes and also include the 90 classess the SSD Mobilenet model contains

Tags: tensorflow

I am building a new tensorflow model based off of SSD V1 coco model in order to perform real time object detection in a video but i m trying to find if there is a way to build a model where I can add a new class to the existing model so that my model has all those 90 classes available in SSD MOBILENET COCO v1 model and also contains the new classes that i want to classify.

For example, I have created training data for two classes: man, woman
Now, I built a new tensorflow model that identifies a man and/or woman in a video. However, my model does not have the other 90 classes present in original SSD Mobilenet model. I am looking for a way to concatenate both models or pass more than one model to my code to detect the objects.

If you have any questions or if I am not clear, please feel free to probe me further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The only way i find is you need to get dataset of SSD Mobilenet model on which it was trained.
2. Make sure all the images are present in one directory and annotations in another directory.
3. We should have a corresponding annotation file for each image file 
   ex: myimage.jpg and myimage.xml
4. If all the images of your customed dataset are of same formate with SSD Mobilenet model then annotate it with a tool called LabelImg.
5. Add that images and annotated files to respective images and annotations directory where we have already saved SSD Mobilenet.
6. Try regenerate new TFrecord and continue with remaining procedure on it.

Comment: Yeah, this process would work. I was wondering if there is another way where we dont have to find out the datasets used to build SSD MobileNet model

Comment: Dear friends,
I am facing a similar problem and I'd like to know if you have found any way to add a custom class to the 90 COCO classes without having the original datasets. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use transfer learning with Tensorflow API.
Transfer learning allows you to load re-trained network and modify the fully connected layer by introducing your classes.
There is full description for this in the following references:

1. [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#3)
2. A good explanation [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9)
3. Tensorflow API [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) for more details

Also you can use [google cloud platform](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md) for better and faster results:

I wish this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way you can add your classes to the existing 90 classes without using the dataset it is previously trained with. Your only way is to use that dataset plus your own and retrain the model.